# <div [innerHTML]=.... not working with iframe html> in angular2 html inject

Tags: angular, angular2-security

`<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>` isn't working when the html contains an Iframe. I've tried to do some security bypass with `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(...`, but it still doesn't work.

[Here's the demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3zgLWDcgKQAkBXUDyTBc?p=preview) with angular2 not injecting correctly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[**Working PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MxiP0Yi7kBzvw5CWCQWo?p=preview)

You need to use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` for that, and need to assign and use the 
sanitized `html` like this

```ts
this.html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.html);
```

Comment: After the stable version of angular
import { DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser'; Should be 
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
And change the injection in the constructor as well.

Comment: I have added video URL in iframe, rendered fine but not working on Play, any reason?

Answer (score 6):

**DomSanitizationService is outdated from angular2 RC6**

If you are using angular2 RC5 use this-

```
DomSanitizationService
```

If you are moving to angular2 RC6 use this-

```
DomSanitize
```

Here, is the complete example

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Then add in constructure

```
private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
```

and apply sanitizer on your variable like this

```
let text = <iframe width="977" height="733" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
text = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text);
return text;
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: Innerhtml Angular 8]

`this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` takes string as input and makes it SafeHtml.I have done this in Angular 8.