# Iframe with youtube video embed don't appear in ionic2+

Tags: html, angularjs, json, iframe, ionic2

I have a request in my web api that give me a Json like this

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "ID": 9710,
    "post_author": 2,
    "post_date": "31/08/2017",
    "post_content": "Assim como aconteceu no primeiro Destiny, a <strong>Bungie</strong> e a <strong>Activision</strong> lançaram nesta quinta-feira (31) um trailer live action de <strong>Destiny 2</strong>, com direito a <strong>Cayde-6</strong>  fazendo um discurso motivacional, lembrando que todas as coisas que você ama na Terra se foram (inclusive os cachorrinhos).<br><br><div class=\"video\"><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/UhE6B3MPsUM'></iframe></div><br><br>O trailer por <strong>Jordan Vogt-Roberts</strong> mais conhecido pelo seu trabalho em <a href=\"http://nextseason.com.br/critica-kong-a-ilha-da-caveira/\"><strong>Kong: A ilha da Caveira</strong></a>.<br><br>A nossa aventura em Destiny 2 começa com os <strong>Guardiões</strong> buscando vingança após ter a última cidade segura na Terra destruída pela Legião Vermelha, liderada pelo poderoso <strong>Ghaul</strong>. Com isso, será necessário que exploremos novos mundos do sistema solar, em busca de armas e habilidades para vencer essa guerra e recuperar a nossa luz.<br><br><strong>Destiny 2</strong> será lançado em 6 de setembro pra <strong>Xbox One </strong>e <strong>PS4</strong>. No PC o jogo será lançado um mês depois no dia 24 de outubro.<br><br><strong><a href=\"http://nextseason.com.br/?s=destiny+2\">Saiba mais sobre Destiny 2</a></strong>",
    "post_title": "Destiny 2 ganha trailer live action ao som Sabotage",
    "post_name": "destiny-2-ganha-trailer-live-action-ao-som-sabotage",
    "guid": "http://nextseason.com.br/?p=9710",
    "meta_value": 9711,
    "id_post_img": 9711,
    "link_imagem": "http://nextseason.com.br/wp-content/uploads/live-action-destiny-2.jpg",
    "id_post_categoria": 9710,
    "category": "Games"
}
```

and in app using Ionic 2 i put the code

```
<div [innerHtml]="post.post_content"> </div>
```

where post.post_content is the post_content from my request.

inside the post_content has an  with a embed youtube video, but when i run the, the video does not show. In debug appears like that.

```
<div>Assim como aconteceu no primeiro Destiny, a 
<strong>Bungie</strong> e a <strong>Activision</strong>
lançaram nesta quinta-feira (31) um trailer live action de <strong>Destiny 
2</strong>, com direito a <strong>Cayde-6</strong> &nbsp;fazendo um discurso 
motivacional, lembrando que todas as coisas que você ama na Terra se foram 
(inclusive os cachorrinhos).<br><br><div class="video"></div><br><br>O 
trailer por&nbsp;<strong>Jordan Vogt-Roberts</strong>
```

the div element always shows empty. Someone can help me? have any idea why this occurs?

Sorry my english!

Comment: thats a security measurement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446235/div-innerhtml-not-working-with-iframe-html-in-angular2-html-inject

Comment: yeah you are correct, i creat a pipe that do this for me. Thanks for the answer dude