# Angular 4 how to use innerHtml with *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, ngfor

I have below response from api

```
[  
   {  
      "Cinema_strName":"dfdsfsd, Ahmedabad",
      "Cinema_strID":"HIWB",
      "Cinema_strBannerImg":"F&BCombo.jpg",
      "cinema_addr":"fsdfsdfr,Drive-in Road, 380052, ",
      "cinema_loc":"<iframe src=\"fsdfsdfdsfsfdsfdsffsf4!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x6a9f5938cfed5cd2!2sCarnival+Cinemas!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1467809324170\" width=\"600\" height=\"450\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
      "cinema_mob":0
   }
]
```

I want to get iframe from the api and append to div map

For that I wrote in `TS` file

```
  this.common.createAPIService('api/cinemas/List?CityName='+city, '').subscribe((result: any) => {
  if(result.length){
    this.cinema = result;
    console.log(this.cinema);
  }else{
      alert('Cinema not found');
  }
})
```

**html template:**

```
<div class="map" *ngFor="let map of cinema">
     <div [innerHTML]="map.cinema_loc"></div>
 </div>
```

But HTML is not comming but if I bind normally that is like below

```
<div class="map" *ngFor="let map of cinema">
     <div>{{map?.cinema_loc}}</div>
  </div>
```

Iframe in showing in text format.

How can I append as html?

Please help.

AS per given solution I had tried below

```
 this.common.createAPIService('api/cinemas/List?CityName='+city, '').subscribe((result: any) => {
  if(result.length){
    this.cinema = result;
    this.cinema = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.cinema);

    console.log(this.cinema);
  }else{
      alert('Cinema not found');
  }
```

But does'nt work. If I console.log this.cinema.cinema_loc. Getting undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<div \[innerHTML\]=.... not working with iframe html> in angular2 html inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446235/div-innerhtml-not-working-with-iframe-html-in-angular2-html-inject)

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: In console getting cinema_loc undefined

Comment: Have you tried it using the null operator (?), like so: `[innerHTML]="map?.cinema_loc"`

Comment: Yes. I tried this also but not working

Answer (score 7):

I think this would work.
First Solution is:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let testString of testStrings">
<label [innerHtml]="testString"></label>
</ng-container>
```

and Second Solution is :

```
this.testString = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.testString);
```

Comment: this is the answer in the duplicate link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446235/div-innerhtml-not-working-with-iframe-html-in-angular2-html-inject

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to sanitize it as Angular is stripping it due to Security reasons:

Use this in Template:

```
<div class="map" *ngFor="let map of cinema">
  <div [innerHTML]="safeCinema(map.cinema_loc)"></div>
</div>
```

Use this in Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  cinema = [
    {
      "Cinema_strName": "dfdsfsd, Ahmedabad",
      "Cinema_strID": "HIWB",
      "Cinema_strBannerImg": "F&BCombo.jpg",
      "cinema_addr": "fsdfsdfr,Drive-in Road, 380052, ",
      "cinema_loc": "<iframe src=\"fsdfsdfdsfsfdsfdsffsf4!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x6a9f5938cfed5cd2!2sCarnival+Cinemas!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1467809324170\" width=\"600\" height=\"450\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
      "cinema_mob": 0
    }
  ];

  safeCinema(cinemaLoc) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(cinemaLoc);
  }

}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sanitization?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: this is the answer in the duplicate link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446235/div-innerhtml-not-working-with-iframe-html-in-angular2-html-inject

Comment: @aloisdg, sorry about that. Didn't get the time to check for possible duplicates. :)

Comment: I do see the `Connecting to dev server...` markup over there. Not sure why it isn't loading, Did you try checking by loading it directly in a div just to test whether the iframe source actually works?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `map` variable is undefined on the first pass for some reason. Try this modification to the previous answer:

`<div [innerHTML]="map?.cinema_loc"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

### Just perform following checks -

1. Anything related to dynamic html injection needs to go through `DomSanitizer`. That you can do through @Injecting the `DomSanitizer` and calling the method `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`.
2. Make sure `iframe` `src` you are passing is correct.

You can see demo in action here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ixzyza

*Note: In demo link I am using https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt as iframe src.*